# Matlab eigs() function: incorrect eigenvectors

Tags: matlab, matrix, eigenvector

I am using eigs to find largest 330 eigenvalues, the eigenvalues converges and found pretty match with eig (full (my matrix)), But the eigen vectors didn't match well, it is showing completely new eigen vector. I couldn't find out, what is the problem? here is my matrix, please see if any step is missing in my analysis. I need accurate eigen vectors.

my matrix= sparse size: 456 x 456

here is the code:

`[V D]=eigs(M4,330,'la');`

for full matrix,

```
[V1 D1]=eig(full(M4));
```

thanks in advance.

here is my matrix in *.mat format.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByrCuBh4SoO_ZGF3X2hHZWlQNFU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: How do you compare the results? I hope you are not doing it manually.

Comment: I assume that you know that eigenvectors are not unique ([see here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/235396/eigenvalues-are-unique)). Despite the similar names, `eig` and `eigs` use *completely* different methods.

Comment: Also, FYI, `rank(full(M4))` is only `315`. Your matrix is effectively singular. Unless, this is just an example, 456-by-456 is a pretty small matrix. If you want such a large percentage of the eigenvalues you should be using `eig`, which will be [faster and more accurate](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eigs.html#moreabout).

Comment: to compare result i did relative norm

Comment: thanks for your comment sir, this is just an example.

Comment: What is the definition of the relative norm?

Comment: actually its relative error, norm(V_eigs(:,i)-V_eig(:,i))/norm(V_eig(:,i)), its over 100%